# What is the equivalent of a C# Task in python

Tags: c#, python, task

I need to translate my c# code to python. I have a Task in c# and need to translate it to python. Here is a piece of the code:

```
List<Task> t = new List<Task>();
for(int i = 0; i < _tasks.Count; i++)
{
     var theTask = _tasks[i];
     t.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => theTask.SAPTask.Execute(theTask.index, theTask.WindowCount)));
}
t.ForEach(x => x.Wait());
```

This little piece of code is crucial to run my program. I need python to run all the tasks in the list in separate threads, and block the main thread until all the tasks are completed. Does python have this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

> I need Python to run all the tasks in the list *and then block the main thread until all the tasks are completed*.

The main use case for `Task` is to **avoid** blocking the main thread, so the user can interact with application while the work is pushed to different threads.

Are you just trying to implement parallelism between individual pieces of work?
If you're using Python 3.2, there is [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) that does look like TPL in a way.

Comment: Tasks may help avoid blocking the main thread, but in this particular example even in the original program the main thread is blocked waiting for all the tasks to complete. I'm guessing it's not a problem for the program at hand.

Comment: @retuna: Exactly. Still, although the main thread is blocked, the individual tasks run concurrently in his example, so I figured that's what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A task is just an operation, run as a thread of it's own. Just make a thread and let it do something specific, and you have your Task.

Comment: This is not correct. .NET `Task`s *may* be scheduled on a different thread, but this is not always the case, and in most situations they run on a pool of threads, rather than each get their own. It's usually too wasteful to spin off a thread for each task.

Comment: Even if the thread comes from a thread pool, it's a thread of it's own for the task's duration. Which is a reason not to use the thread pool for long-running tasks.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your message, for which I apologize. This is indeed correct.